# Windows 8 and Ubuntu in UEFI mode - Ubuntu only boots when entering Windows 8 first

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi

I have a problem, which is that the only way to start is when I start Ubuntu 14.04 Windows 8 first then (Shift + reset) and enter to boot from USB and Ubuntu there appears, after selecting newly see GRUB.

[image]

I've done the installation as follows: first Windows 8.1 UPDATE1 with Rufus, then Ubuntu 14.04 with Rufus, installed everything with UEFI enabled.
I tried to repair the GRUB bootloader using Boot-Repair, but I had no success. Here is my [Boot-Repair Boot Info Script](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8586623/).

Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: If the OS is recognized, you should be able to go into Troubleshoot > Advanced > Default and select Ubuntu as the main entry. From there, it should come to the above slash screen to load both. 

I had the same issue where it would default to Windows 8, and I'd need to perform the same as you for Linux. If this doesn't help, from within Windows run a CMD and modify the boatload to point to Ububtu first. I cannot recall off the top of my head this method, so Google "Modify MBR file within Windows".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using ReFind as your UEFI manager and discard grub altogether. I purged grub off my system and have been using ReFind to select between Windows and Ubuntu. You don't need grub because the Linux kernel itself acts like a UEFI application and can be booted without using grub. Much cleaner as I don't need grub as a middleman to boot my Ubuntu. And I like the ReFind interface.

Tip: If you don't need secure boot, turn it off. It sometimes causes problems for ReFind.